# Elements declared in HTML after Custom Element do not render

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, shadow-dom, custom-element

**REAL BIG EDIT:**
Hello there, this is edit number 3. This one is here on top because, well, it changes the fundamental question of this post.
In short, I tried putting `h1`s both before and after a single Custom Element. Well... only what I have putted *before* rendered. So, I guess the problem is that **no elements are rendered after my Custom Elements**.
I'm not deleting my old observations below for recording purposes, since someone may happen to strumble in this problem and understand it wrong, like me.

---

I'm trying a little bit with Custom Elements v1 on Chrome but things aren't quite right.

The custom element in question - I call it `range-slider` - is just a bunch of `1 label`, 1 `input range` and 1 `input number` put together and styled, plus `number` and `range` are bind to each other.

RangeSlider.js:

```
class RangeSlider extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        this.initShadowDom();
        this.flowInputToElem("field", "slider");
        this.flowInputToElem("slider", "field");
    }

    initShadowDom() {
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
        shadowRoot.innerHTML = this.template;
    }
    flowInputToElem(inputId, elemId) {
        const shadowRoot = this.shadowRoot;
        const input = shadowRoot.getElementById(inputId);
        const elem = shadowRoot.getElementById(elemId);

        input.addEventListener("input", e => {
            const min = parseFloat(elem.min);
            const max = parseFloat(elem.max);
            const newVal = parseFloat(input.value);

            elem.value = newVal > max
                ? max
                : newVal < min
                    ? min
                    : newVal;
        });
    }

    get label() {
        return this.getAttribute("label") || "Range slider";
    }
    get min() {
        return this.getAttribute("min") || 0;
    }
    get max() {
        return this.getAttribute("max");
    }
    get value() {
        return this.getAttribute("value") || 0;
    }

    get template() {
        return `
            <style>
                @import url('style/appearance.css');
                @import url('style/color.css');
                @import url('style/size.css');
                @import url('style/position.css');
                @import url('components/rangeSlider/style/slider.css');
            </style>
            <form class="w-max arial">
                <label for="field">${this.label}:</label>
                <div class="flx flx-middle">
                    <input id="slider" type="range" min="${this.min}" max="${this.max}" value="${this.value}" class="slider 
                        w-big">
                    <input id="field" type="number" min="0" max="${Infinity}" value="${this.value}" class="mrg-none 
                        spin-none brd-none w-small bg-transp txt-center">
                </div>
            </form>
        `;
    }
}

window.customElements.define('range-slider', RangeSlider);
```

In my understanding, everything seems to be fine with `range-slider`. In fact, it works; well, kind of. If I put more than 1 `range-slider` on my index.html, only the first one is rendered.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pegada de carbono</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/position.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/color.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/size.css">

    <script src="components/rangeSlider/RangeSlider.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="pos-abs h-fill w-fill mrg-none pdg-none bg-white">
    <range-slider label="example 1" min="0" max="100" value="25"></range-slider>
    <range-slider label="example 2" min="0" max="100" value="45"></range-slider>
    <range-slider label="example 3" min="0" max="100" value="65"></range-slider>
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome: 
[image: Only the first range-slider happened to render]

Why is that?

**EDIT:**
Strangely enough, when I append the element by JavaScript it renders as expected.

```
const rangeSlider = document.createElement("range-slider");
rangeSlider.label = "example 4";
rangeSlider.value = "65";
rangeSlider.max = "1000";
rangeSlider.min = "0";

document.body.appendChild(rangeSlider);
```

**EDIT 2:**
Okay, I have done some more testing and weirder things happened:
 1. if I put 1 native element then 1 `range-slider` (or vice-versa),
    everything renders okay;
 2. if I put `range-slider`, native component then another `range-slider`, only the first `range-slider` renders; (which means not even the native component is okay)
 3. if I try to add `range-slider`s inside another Custom Element, the outer Custom Element is good and `range-slider` number 1 too, but all the other `range-slider`s are not.

Comment: Updated post with some more details.

Comment: Updated the post to address new question. In short, I thought that I was having problems to render N-ary Custom Elements. After some tests, it seems that I'm not capable of rendering **any** elements declared by HTML after a Custom one.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and modified it slightly and ran in in the snippet mode here on this page and it worked fine.

```js
    class OtherEl  extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();

        this.attachShadow({mode: "open"}).innerHTML = '<div style="background-color: yellow;padding:4px;"><range-slider label="inner slider" min="0" max="100" value="5"></range-slider></div>';
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define('other-el', OtherEl);

    class RangeSlider extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
      }

      connectedCallback() {
        if (this.shadowRoot.childElementCount === 0) {
          this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = this.template;
          this.flowInputToElem("field", "slider");
          this.flowInputToElem("slider", "field");
        }
      }

      flowInputToElem(inputId, elemId) {
        const shadowRoot = this.shadowRoot;
        const input = shadowRoot.getElementById(inputId);
        const elem = shadowRoot.getElementById(elemId);

        input.addEventListener("input", e => {
          const min = elem.min;
          const max = elem.max;
          const newVal = input.value;
          elem.value = newVal > max ? max : newVal < min ? min : newVal;
        });
      }

      get label() {
        return this.getAttribute("label") || "Range slider";
      }
      get min() {
        return parseFloat(this.getAttribute("min") || '0');
      }
      get max() {
        return parseFloat(this.getAttribute("max") || '100');
      }
      get value() {
        return parseFloat(this.getAttribute("value") || '0');
      }

      get template() {
        return `
          <style>
            @import url('style/appearance.css');
            @import url('style/color.css');
            @import url('style/size.css');
            @import url('style/position.css');
            @import url('components/rangeSlider/style/slider.css');
          </style>
          <form class="w-max arial">
            <label for="field">${this.label}:</label>
            <div class="flx flx-middle">
              <input id="slider" type="range" min="${this.min}" max="${this.max}" value="${this.value}" class="slider w-big">
              <input id="field" type="number" min="0" max="${Infinity}" value="${this.value}" class="mrg-none spin-none brd-none w-small bg-transp txt-center">
              </div>
          </form>
        `;
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define('range-slider', RangeSlider);
```

```html
  <h1>Before</h1>
  <range-slider label="example 1" min="0" max="100" value="25"></range-slider>
  <h2>After 1</h2>
  <range-slider label="example 2" min="0" max="100" value="45"></range-slider>
  <h2>After 2</h2>
  <range-slider label="example 3" min="0" max="100" value="65"></range-slider>
  <h2>After 3</h2>
  <other-el></other-el>
  <h2>After OtherEl</h2>
```

Then I ran it on my server and saw what you were seeing. Only one element showed.

[image: Only one showing]

But I noticed this error in the dev tools:

[image]

Since I don't have your CSS files my CSS is not loading and this is causing something to crash in the Web Component code.

When I commented out the `<style>` tag in your template:

```js
  get template() {
    return `
      <!-- <style>
        @import url('style/appearance.css');
        @import url('style/color.css');
        @import url('style/size.css');
        @import url('style/position.css');
        @import url('components/rangeSlider/style/slider.css');
      </style> -->
      <form class="w-max arial">
        <label for="field">${this.label}:</label>
        <div class="flx flx-middle">
          <input id="slider" type="range" min="${this.min}" max="${this.max}" value="${this.value}" class="slider w-big">
          <input id="field" type="number" min="0" max="${Infinity}" value="${this.value}" class="mrg-none spin-none brd-none w-small bg-transp txt-center">
          </div>
      </form>
    `;
  }
}
```

Then all 5 show up, including the one inside my other element.

[image]